# How to put two rows of data together from MySQL in RSS feed

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, formatting, rss

I've got a code that displays an RSS feed but it won't display the main content.

```
 <?PHP
 include("../config.php");
 #// Timetable Clearup Variabls
$yesterday = strtotime('yesterday');
$yesterdow = date('l',$yesterday);
$order = "SELECT * FROM timetable WHERE day = '$yesterdow' ORDER BY time";
$result = mysql_query($order);
$yesterdayd = date('F jS, Y', time()-86400);

    //SET XML HEADER
    header('Content-type: text/xml');

    //CONSTRUCT RSS FEED HEADERS
    $output = '<rss version="2.0">';
    $output .= '<channel>';
    $output .= "<title>Timetable - {$yesterdayd} </title>";
    $output .= '<description>Timetable.</description>';
    $output .= '<link>http://example.com/</link>';
 ###   $output .= '<copyright>Your copyright details</copyright>';

    //BODY OF RSS FEED
   $output .= '<item>';
        $output .= "<title>Timetable for $yesterdayd</title>";
        $output .= "<description><td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['username']) . "</td><td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['time']) . "</td></description>";
        $output .= '<link>Link to Item</link>';
        $output .= '<pubDate>Date Published</pubDate>';
   $output .= '</item> ';

    //CLOSE RSS FEED
   $output .= '</channel>';
   $output .= '</rss>';

    //SEND COMPLETE RSS FEED TO BROWSER
    echo($output);

?>
```

The bit I'm having issue with is:

```
 $output .= "<description><td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['username']) . "</td><td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['time']) . "</td></description>";
```

I basically need to output the data from each row onto the feed.

Here's how I can do it normally (into a table, which is the format I'd like):

```
<?php 
include("../config.php");

#// Timetable Clearup Variabls
$yesterday = strtotime('yesterday');
$yesterdow = date('l',$yesterday);

echo "<table width=\"580px\" class=\"board\" border=\>";

$order = "SELECT * FROM timetable WHERE day = '$yesterdow' ORDER BY time";
$result = mysql_query($order);

// Error checking
if (!$result) {
  // output error, take other action
}
else {
  while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
     // Append all results onto an array
     $rowset[] = $row;
       echo "<tr><td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['username']) . "</td><td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['time']) . "</td></tr>";
  }
}





?>
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you mean you want to display the rss in a table? Do you want to create HTML or RSS (XML)?  Or maybe you are talking about transforming the RSS into an HTML display?  One way is to use [XSLT](http://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/) for that.

In your RSS-generating script, you don't have a `$row` variable defined for every feed item. You need to just place the `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))` around the rss item output - something like this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $output .= '<item>';
    $output .= "<title>Timetable for $yesterdayd</title>";
    $output .= "<description><td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['username']) . "</td><td>" . htmlspecialchars($row['time']) . "</td></description>";
    $output .= '<link>Link to Item</link>';
    $output .= '<pubDate>Date Published</pubDate>';
    $output .= '</item>';
}
```

EDIT: on re-examining your code: you also need to break up the fields in your `description` tag.  You should not put `td` tags in there - the RSS elements are not (normally) meant to contain HTML marked-up data.

Something like this (if this meaning makes sense):

```
$output = "<description>
    <username>" . htmlspecialchars($row['username']) . "</username>
    <time>" .     htmlspecialchars($row['time']) . "</time>
</description>";
```